# Visio Stencils for MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visio

Does anyone have a good set of Visio Stencils for MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 3):

Some versions of Visio have database support built in.  There are a couple of links on the MVP site for Visio:

New URL: http://visio.mvps.org/3rdParty/default.html
Old URL: http://visio.mvps.org/3rdparty.htm

Hope this helps!
Jeff

Comment: updated the URL to the links, the mvps.org website was reorganized.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself but there is one at http://visiotoolbox.com/downloads.aspx?resourceid=1&aid=562